# PodSixNet multiplayer networking library for Python game based on Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, network-programming, multiplayer

I have  trying to figure out how to make my game using tkinter multiplayer using PodSixNet.

Then I launch server.py and main.py from two terminal sessions and click on the button, which triggers Deck.confirm_move(). Deck.confirm_move() is supposed to send info to the server:

```
connection.Send({"action": "myaction", "myvar": 33})
```

The problem is that the response is visible on the server only when I close the window:

```
> python ./server.py 
Starting server on localhost
('boxesServe=', '<__main__.BoxesServer listening 127.0.0.1:31425 at 0x7f7de91193b0>')
new connection: channel =  <__main__.ClientChannel connected 127.0.0.1:56286 at 0x7f7de9119638>

#THIS APPEARS WHEN I CLOSE THE WINDOW
**{'action': 'myaction', 'myvar': 33}
('myaction:', {'action': 'myaction', 'myvar': 33})**


> python ./main.py 
('connection=', '<PodSixNet.EndPoint.EndPoint 127.0.0.1:31425 at 0x7f447af96cf8>')
```

I have several files/classes, so I made a minimal example out of them. If you have comments on how I organize my scripts please let me know.

main.py:

```
#launch the GUI and mainloop
from PodSixNet.Connection import ConnectionListener, connection
import Gui
import config as cfg
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui_instance = Gui.Gui()
    gui_instance.main()
    cfg.canvas.mainloop()

    pass
    while 1:
        connection.Pump()
        gui_instance.Pump()
```

config.py:

```
#Here I initialize objects/parameters that are shared between scripts. 
#Is this good practice?
win = None
canvas = None
deck = False
```

Gui.py:

```
#Define the GUI with a canvas, buttons, etc. Call self.Connect()
import Tkinter as tk

from PodSixNet.Connection import ConnectionListener, connection
import config as cfg
from Deck import Deck
class Gui(ConnectionListener):
  def __init__(self):
    cfg.win=tk.Tk()

    """Create cfg.canvas"""
    cfg.canvas=tk.Canvas(cfg.win,height=300,width=300,name="canvas")
    """Buttons"""  self.btnConf=tk.Button(cfg.win,text="Confirm",width=6,name="btnConf",bg="white",anchor=tk.W)
    self.btnConf.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.buttonCallback)
    self.btnConf_window = cfg.canvas.create_window(50,50,anchor=tk.NW, window=self.btnConf)
    cfg.canvas.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 5)

    self.Connect()  # <--- PodSixNet's Connect 

  def buttonCallback(self, event):
    cfg.deck.confirm_move()

  def main(self):
    """Deal deck"""
    cfg.deck = Deck()
```

Deck.py:

```
#Here is where the actions of the game are run. 
#Here I want to use Send to send information to the server
from PodSixNet.Connection import ConnectionListener, connection

class Deck(ConnectionListener):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def confirm_move(self):
    print("connection=",str(connection))
    connection.Send({"action": "myaction", "myvar": 33})
```

server.py:

```
import PodSixNet.Channel
import PodSixNet.Server
from time import sleep    
class ClientChannel(PodSixNet.Channel.Channel):
  def Network(self, data):
    print data

  def Network_myaction(self, data):
    print("myaction:", data)

class BoxesServer(PodSixNet.Server.Server):
  channelClass = ClientChannel

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    PodSixNet.Server.Server.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  def Connected(self, channel, addr):
    print 'new connection: channel = ', channel

print "Starting server on localhost"
boxesServe = BoxesServer()
print("boxesServe=",str(boxesServe))
while True:
    boxesServe.Pump()
    sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the loop in cfg.canvas.mainloop() with a loop calling update() and update_idletasks() on the window object. In your case the while loop becomes:

```
while 1:
  connection.Pump()
  self.Pump()
  cfg.win.update()
  cfg.win.update_idletasks()
```

Because in main.py you now have:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  gui_instance = Gui.Gui()
  gui_instance.main()
  #cfg.canvas.mainloop()
```

Place the while loop  after you initialize the GUI, in the end of Gui.main():

```
def main(self):
  """Deal deck"""
  cfg.deck = Deck() 
  while 1:
    connection.Pump()
    self.Pump()
    cfg.win.update()
    cfg.win.update_idletasks()
```

and you should be all set.